# Passing r values by reference?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20

I frequently write functions that take arguments by non-const reference, but the downside is that I can't pass r-values.

A colleague of mine showed me this piece of code which supposedly solves the problem:

```
#include <iostream>

// example function
int f(int& x) {
    x += 5;
    return x;
}

// is this undefined behaviour?
auto& to_l_value(auto&& x) {
    return x;
}

int main () {
    auto y = f(to_l_value(5)); // usage example
    std::cout << y; // 10
    return 0;
}
```

Is this undefined behaviour because of a dangling reference? (does `5` get destroyed before `f` is called?)

When does the temporary get destroyed?

Comment: Much as `std::move` could have been called `rvalue_cast`, your colleague's `to_l_value` could be called `lvalue_cast`.  I presume you are aware of the big caveats, and why C++ disallowed this happening automatically with non-const references and temporaries.  I strongly urge you to reconsider your practice of frequently writing functions which take arguments by non-const reference; I consider such code to be non-idiomatic (and I do, in part, blame C++ for having "all the defaults are wrong").

Comment: "*I frequently write functions that take arguments by non-const reference, but the downside is that I can't pass r-values.*" This is not a problem that should ever happen. If you have a function that takes a non-const reference, then you are signaling that this parameter is being modified by the function and the outside world needs to see those modifications. If the user has an rvalue, then that means they *do not want* to look at this object anymore. You therefore have a contradiction.

Comment: Is the code in the example just illustrative, or are you actually using references for trivial types like `int`? If the latter, I recommend rethinking that approach, as `int`s fit into registers, but `[const] int&` may generate (potentially multiple) indirect reads if the compiler can't prove that the reference isn't to a global value that may be mutated from other factors.

Comment: @Human Compiler yes this is just illustrative. Of course ints are passed by value.

Comment: @NicolBolas: There certainly are cases where one would want to pass an rvalue: the most basic is a dummy for an “out parameter” that provides ancillary information that isn’t always needed, and another is where the function uses an object that is expensive or impossible to copy in a fashion that relies on mutating it (*e.g.*, it is or contains a state machine) but the final state might or might not be uninteresting.  Either can be addressed with rvalue-reference overloads, of course, and sometimes with forwarding references, but not every API has every conceivable overload.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Temporaries are destroyed (except some exceptions) when full expression is finished.
So you are fine here.

More details about [lifetime](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lifetime#Temporary_object_lifetime):

> All temporary objects are destroyed as the last step in evaluating the full-expression that (lexically) contains the point where they were created, and if multiple temporary objects were created, they are destroyed in the order opposite to the order of creation. This is true even if that evaluation ends in throwing an exception.
>
> There are two exceptions from that:
>
> - The lifetime of a temporary object may be extended by binding to a const lvalue reference or to an rvalue reference (since C++11), see reference initialization for details.
> - The lifetime of a temporary object created when evaluating the default arguments of a default or copy constructor used to initialize an element of an array ends before the next element of the array begins initialization.

Comment: What are the exceptions to this rule ?

Comment: @SomeProgrammer, Lifetime extension must be one of them. For example, `const int& x = 2;` will extend the lifetime of the temporary until `x` is out of scope.

Comment: @SomeProgrammer • *What are the exceptions to this rule ?*  The exceptions are cited in the answer.